# unir dos tablas

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4, msql

lo que quiero hacer es unir dos tablas ya que ambas tienen un dato igual, para cuando haga esa comparacion que ese dato ya no se muestre en la vista o muestre todos los que son diferentes
intente asi

```
public function ModeloConsulta(){
        $query = $this->db->table('setuprun d');
        $query->select('setuprun d.*');
        $query->join('certificados','setuprun d.orderJobNumber = certificados.certificado_calidad_npedido','right');
        $query->where('certificados.certificado_calidad_npedido'); 

        $results = $query->get();
```

pero al hacer un var dum me sale null
entonces no se donde me estoy equivocando para que no muestre esos datos
gracias espero sus opiniones

Comment: hay varias cosas que puedes hacer por ejemplo convertir ese query a un query mysql y validar que el query funciona correctamente, directamente como mysql o utilizando phpmyadmin, lo otro que puedes camboar es el right por un left, otra cosa que veo es que si estas usando "d" como alias esto esta mal: "setuprun d.orderJobNumber" deberia ser simplemente: "d.orderJobNumber", te pregunto sabes que hace cada parte del codigo o estas inventando sin saber la teoria?

Comment: tambien veo que avandonaste esta otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/601693/codeigniter-como-hacer-para-que-una-lista-al-actualizar-quite-ese-registro

Comment: Hola! Estás usando miniSQL? En serio???? Las etiquetas son importantes porque traen la ayuda de las personas que más dominan un tema. Más preguntas: Cómo estás definidas las tablas? Qué datos tienen? (o puedes probar mostrando datos de ejemplo? Cuál es la salida esperada de la consulta? (qué esperas obtener de este query?) Por favor, ve a [edit] y amplía la pregunta para que recibas ayuda más rápido

Comment: hola, muchas gracias a todos, lo que pasa es que soy un poco nueva en todo esto y estoy en mis practicas, entonces me pusieron a desarrollar algunos requerimientos y aun me pierdo un poco :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te hice un par de comentarios y aquí te dejo la respuesta de cómo resolverlo:

Validación con un query:

```
SELECT d.*, c.*
FROM setuprun d
LEFT JOIN certificados c ON d.orderJobNumber = c.certificado_calidad_npedido;
```

Esto debería traerte los datos esperados.

Los cambios en el script:

```
public function ModeloConsulta() {
    $this->db->select('d.*, c.*'); // Selecciona todas las columnas de la tabla 'setuprun' (alias 'd')
    $this->db->from('setuprun d');
    $this->db->join('certificados c', 'd.orderJobNumber = c.certificado_calidad_npedido', 'left'); // Realiza una LEFT JOIN con la tabla 'certificados' (alias 'c')
    
    $query = $this->db->get(); // Ejecuta la consulta

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result(); // Devuelve los resultados de la consulta
    } else {
        return array(); // Si no hay resultados, devuelve un arreglo vacío
    }
}
```

ejemplo en SQLfidle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b81bb8/2

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió bastante, es que aun me pierdo un poco en el uso de join